# Is Surdarshan Chakra mentioned In Vedic literature?

Tags: vishnu, vedas, upanishads, brahmanas

The Surdarshan Chakra is Lord vishnu's weapon mentioned in many puranas and in Itihasas. But is there any reference of  Surdarshana Chakra in Vedic literature (that is Vedas,Upanishads,Brahmans).the wikipedia says **in the Rigveda the Chakra was Vishnu's symbol as the wheel of time**, so where exactly is Chakra of Lord Vishnu mentioned?

Comment: Sudarshan Chakra always confusing for me. My confusion is  whether it's Lord Shiva'a weapon or Lord Vishnu's. Because I heard some stories in which Shiva gave Sudarshan to Vishnu, same as Shiva grant Parshipatarth to many. But Parshuptarth still considered a weapon of Shiva, not weapon of wielder. So whose weapon is Sudarshan? If Sudarsha is really grant to Vishnu by Shiva then how Sudarshan can be considered as weapon of VIshnu. I was confused on this long ago and your question remind me of this confusion of mine ;p

Comment: @Rishabh I think it is weapon of Lord Vishnu and later  scriptures tells that it was given to vishnu by Shiva, you can ask this question on the site.

Comment: _"you can ask this question on the site"_ I can't ask. last few questions of mine back to back gone unanswered continuesly. It Seems my bad luck is running fast these days. If I ask another one then chances are high that this one also will be remain unanswered :( But you can try to ask same. You luck sure not going like mine :)

Comment: @Rishabh Questions left unanswere is not unlucky. Cheer up. Sudarshana chakra is Vishnu's only. There is eternal Sudarshana chakra in Vaikuntha which can only handled by Vishnu. Others can not handle it properly.

Comment: @nogshine Thanks for the info :) But doubt remains. If there are eternal Sudarshan in Vaikuntha then why Vishnu got need to get one from Shiva?

Comment: @Rishabh Vishnu doesn't need a new one from Shiva. Sudarshana is the God of the chakra. Actually, there is a story where Sudarshana asks Shiva to be in him but Shiva rejects softly saying that only Vishnu can be that and others can't. This is from Venkatachala Mahatmyam Vamana Purana Kshetra Khanda but the manuscripts we have are not divided into Khandas. So, that's less famous.

Comment: @nogshine This is new info for me. I want to know more about it. Should I ask it as question so I can know more about it. Coz sure you can't tell all in comments. You must have need more space to write in detail.

Comment: @Rishabh when you say later literature? what do you mean? 
Shiva gives all his weapons to Narayana for the protection of Dharma. He even offers him the highest state, to a point where even if they both fight, then he (Shiva) will choose to lose. All this is from Mahabharatam.  This showed Shiva and Narayana and their origins. They both are different but at the same time, they are two aspects that can't be conceived by the literature or the people writing it. Start with Drona Parva a core Jaya section of Mahabharatam. The same goes for Karna Parva. Purana cant overwrite Itihasa.

Comment: @Vishvam when you say later literature? what do you mean? 
Shiva gives all his weapons to Narayana for the protection of Dharma. He even offers him the highest state, to a point where even if they both fight, then he (Shiva) will choose to lose. All this is from Mahabharatam.  This showed Shiva and Narayana and their origins. They both are different but at the same time, they are two aspects that can't be conceived by the literature or the people writing it. Start with Drona Parva a core Jaya section of Mahabharatam. The same goes for Karna Parva. Purana cant overwrite Itihasa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes surdarshan chakra was called Vishnu s chakra in ancient texts including RIG Veda and  even in valmiki Ramayana it is called Vishnu s Chakra.

> **He, like a rounded wheel, hath in swift motion set his ninety racing steeds** together with the four.Developed, vast in form, with those who sing forth praise, a youth, no more a child, he cometh to our call(Rig veda 1.155.6)

The word Chakra is translated as wheel,even Wikipedia says in Yajurveda vishnu s chakra is mention but till now i could not find a refernce in yajur Veda.

Answer (score 2):

Harihi Om.

Yes, it is. There is a mention of the Sudarshana Chakra in the Sudarshana Upanishad.

> यज्ञोपवीती धृतचक्रधारी यो ब्राह्मणो ब्रह्मविद्ब्रह्मविदां मनीषी हिरण्यमादाय सुदर्शनं कृत्वा वह्निसंयुक्तं स्त्रीशूद्रैर्बाहुभ्यां धारयेत् । तस्माद्गर्भेण जायते । ब्राह्मणस्य शरीरं जायते ।
>
> He who bears a Yajnopavita and Chakra, knowing Brahman, having the knowledge of Brahman, the learned, is Sudarshana, who is firey and bears the women and Shudras, with his two arms. From him, birth takes place with the womb and the Braahmana’s body is born.

-Sudarshana Upanishad

This Upanishad was quoted by Shri Vedaanta Deshika and by Svaami Vijayeendra Teertha Shripaadagalu, in Nyaayamauktikamaala.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sudarshan Chakra is also mentioned in The Sharabha Upanishad.

**Sharabha Upanishad.:**

> ***Salutations to that Rudra whose feet were worshipped by the flower of Vishnu’s eyes and who being pleased gave him the holy wheel (Sudarshan Chakra). 7..***

I hope this clarifies your queries.

Comment: The questioner wants Vedic reference.

Comment: Yes, @SanatanaDhara The Sharabha Upanishad comes under Atharva Veda only. If bedas are trees then, upanishads are like its fruits. ..