# Which is the earliest scripture to describe physical attributes of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu

In the Rig Veda the God called Vishnu has only two characteristics - he is large and is a youth.  When are attributes such as shanka, chakra etc. associated with him?

Comment: Related: [Is Sudarshana Chakra mentioned in Vedic literature?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21925/is-surdarshan-chakra-mentioned-in-vedic-literature)

Answer (score 4):

Narayana suktam tells some physical attributes-

> nīlatoyadamadhyasthād vidyullekheva bhāsvarā, nīvāraśūkavattanvī pītā
>   bhāsvatyaṇūpamā.
>
> Brilliant like a streak of lightning set in the midst of the blue
>   rain-bearing clouds, slender like the awn of a paddy grain, yellow
>   (like gold) in colour, in subtlety comparable to the minute atom,
>   glows splendid.

Skin colour like rain bearing cloud, slender- and golden tint due to being srinivasa.

Shatpatha brahmana mentions Vishnu the son of aditi (vamana) as a dwarf taking over 3 worlds

> They then said: "Let us share in this earth along with yourselves! Let
>   a part of it be ours!" The Asuras replied rather grudgingly: 'As much
>   as this Vishnu lies upon, and no more, we give you!' Now Vishnu was a
>   dwarf.... By it they obtained (sam-vid) this entire earth; and because
>   they obtained by it this entire (earth), therefore it (the sacrificial
>   ground) is called vedi (the altar).